# Allowed memory size exhausted error when create block and set template

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1

Hello I am using magmodule rich snippet where this code block add some snippet to catalogue page:

```
$snip_html = $block->getLayout()
                     ->createBlock('snippets/products')
                     ->setTemplate('magmodules/snippets/widget.phtml')
                     ->toHtml();
```

But this is generating error as follow:

> Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   53660871 bytes) in ob_get_clean called at
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php (263)

Even if I emptied the '**magmodules/snippets/widget.phtml**' then also error persist there but if I do exit at the end of phtml file then there is no error.

So what is the issue here and how to debug this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set your memory_limit to be greater than 756MB

```
memory_limit = 756M
```

You can check your memory_limit value in your php.ini file or create a PHP file in your Magento root to check the current memory_limit value

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Please find the memory_limit values recommended by Magento in 2.X

> Compiling code or deploying static assets, 756M
>
> Installing and updating Magento components from Magento Marketplace,
>   2G
>
> Testing, ~3-4G

Comment: but I want to know the cause that why there is memory exhausted error even if phtml is empty

Comment: Even though PHTML is empty the objects created for classes used in this block class and others related to this will be instantiated which will require memory to instantiate them

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation. Please can you also tell is there any alternative to escape this exception if do not want to increase my memory limit.

Comment: It is not possible Magento Recommends the following values for memory limit Compiling code or deploying static assets, 756M
Installing and updating Magento components from Magento Marketplace, 2G
Testing, ~3-4G

Comment: but if I want any try catch solution for this or any php approach then is there any way as right now I am unable to increase my live site memory limit so is there any other handling as it is not required to executed above function

Comment: Try to find the exact code consuming more memory and try to fix it using  memory_get_usage();

Comment: I know ->createBlock('snippets/products') this is getting exception but what if want to take it in try catch block

Comment: please can you let me know which block has class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes and where it is used?

Comment: vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php The layout file is in vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml. Are you asking these details or anything else?